Including number of nodes per class in GNN training data
I am using pytorch-geometric to train a binary node classification model where I provide a graph with nodes with some attributes and the model returns the class of each node. My training data set includes over 1000 graphs. No mask is used. My data is such that, for each graph, I can calculate the number of nodes for each class. So this could be seen as a model that just distributes the nodes of class 1 among all of the nodes in the graph, depending on the node attributes of the graph.
Because I can calculate how many nodes of each class I have in each graph, it occurred to me that I could use that number as an extra input to the model. That way I will at least start with the right number of nodes for each class and the training would be focused on distributing them.
My model consists of two graph convolution layers GCNConv each with a tanh activation. Afterwards I have a Linear layer which does the classification. So,
class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(GCN, self).__init__()
    torch.manual_seed(12345)
    self.conv1 = GCNConv(3, 4)
    self.conv2 = GCNConv(4, 4)
    self.classifier = Linear(4, 2)

def forward(self, x, edge_index):
    h = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
    h = h.tanh()
    h = self.conv2(h, edge_index)
    h = h.tanh()  # Final GNN embedding space.
    h = self.classifier(h)
    
    out = F.log_softmax(h,dim=1)

    return out, h

The question is: what would be the best way to incorporate the information regarding the number of nodes for each class into the model?
